# Character Sprite in a Java Android Game with buggy movement when using two fingers

Tags: java, android

The following code I wrote does what I want, a touch on the left or right side of the screen to move the sprite left or right and stop at the edge of the phone screen.  **The issue I'm having is when you do a fast motion of touching the right side of the screen, letting go while using another finger to touch the left side of the screen to change direction will yield a result of the sprite still moving to the right side of the screen despite you wanting to move left.**  In order to fix this, you need to let go completely for at least 0.5sec then press the other direction to start moving in that direction, which I don't want to have to live with.  If anyone has any tips/help for this, please let me know!

**MAIN ACTIVITY CLASS METHOD:**

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
            CharacterSprite.touchedX = x;
            break;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
            CharacterSprite.touchedX = 0;
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

**CHARACTERSPRITE CLASS METHOD:**

```
public void update() {
    if (touchedX != 0) {
        if (touchedX < screenWidth / 2) {
            if (!(xVelocity < 0)) {
                xVelocity = xVelocity * -1;
            }
            if (!(x > 0)) {
                touchedX = 0;
                return;
            }
            x += xVelocity;
        }
        if (touchedX > screenWidth / 2) {
            if (!(xVelocity > 0)) {
                xVelocity = xVelocity * -1;
            }
            if (!(x < screenWidth - image.getWidth())) {
                touchedX = 0;
                return;
            }
            x += xVelocity;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know that part of Android well, but I imagine you might have to check and keep track of the different pointers. See more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391818/how-do-you-use-motionevent-action-pointer-index-shift and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent?hl=en .

Comment: What is the frequency of `update()` method? How many times does it get called in 1 second ?

Comment: update() method is being called 60 times per 1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you handling MotionEvent will not work for multitouch events. Each finger (action pointer) data stored as an array and you need to handle each entry separately. Here is the lesson on handling multitouch events:

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi